# How to check continuous function $f$ has extension?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, compactness, connectedness

**Question**:

given,

$S= \{(x,y)∈\mathbb{R^2}: -1≤x≤1, -1≤y≤1\}$ and,

$T=S-\{(0,0)\}$

and let $f$ be continuous function from $T$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then choose the correct,

(a) Image of $f$ must be connected.

(b)Image of $f$ must be compact.

(C) any such continuous function $f$ can be extended to a continuous function from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$

(d) if $f$ can be extended to continuous function from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then image of $f$ must be bounded!

**My attempt**: I had done with (a) and (d) and they are **correct**! But I am not able to **discard** (b) and (c). For (b) I know, continuous image of compact set is compact, but i am not able to discard/ prove (b).

Please help me :-(, in (b) and (c) only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both $(b)$ and $(c)$ are not true. My counter examples are as follows:

For $(b)$ consider the supremum norm induced from $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $f$. i.e $f(x,y):=\sup\{\vert x\vert\ , \vert y\vert \}$. Then the image of $f$ is $(0,1]$, which is not closed and not compact.

For $(c)$ consider the map $f(x,y)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. This is a continuous function which is not bounded. Therefore by $(d)$ it cannot be extended to $S$.

Comment: Your c example also works for b.

Comment: Thanks sir, for, reply. got c) but, How you can say image of $f$ is $(0,1]$? Did you defined $f$ in $(b)$ ?

Comment: I added the definition. Also as stated before the counter example for $(c)$ works for $(b)$ as well, which I did not think of at the time.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, for giving your valuable time.

Comment: You're welcome. I was pleased I could be of help.